# Show posts from two specific category in WP_Query

Tags: posts, wp-query, query-posts, tax-query, multi-taxonomy-query

I've two category employee and full-time. If a post publish in both (employee and full-time) category then the post will show in his specific section. If post has only employee category, not full-time or has only full-time, not employee, then this post will not show in the post block.

How can I do this? What will be the query of this relationship between two category??

Here is my code -

```
'tax_query'         =>  array(
    'relation'      =>  'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array('employee', 'full-time'),
    )
)
```

Please help me to figure it out.

I've also tried with this method, but it's not working anymore. I've the same issue. Go here for better understand understand my problem - [Query only Posts from Both of Two Category?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51850/query-only-posts-from-both-of-two-category?newreg=31115cb3d9bb4109babb3a0aaeab516c)

Comment: Show your whole query, not just the tax_query. And is `slug` really the field name?

Comment: The accepted [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51852) for the linked question used `'operator' => 'AND'` in the taxonomy query clause, so have you tried adding that right below the `'terms' => array(...)` line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to show only posts that have both `employee` and `full-time` categories.

If that is the case than you can do the following.

Because you haven't posted the full query args I will only show the `tax_query` part

```
'tax_query'         =>  array(
    'relation'      =>  'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'employee',
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'full-time',
    )
)
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Solved. Thanks a lot.